# How to reset value of DateTime / byte variables?

Tags: c#, datetime, byte, nullable, reset

I'm working on a C# project where I declare two class variables:

```
DateTime creationDate;
byte exRecNo;
```

The program has a while loop in which those variables get their values assigned.
I would like to reset their values to null after every iteration through the loop so as not to retain values from the previous trip through the loop.

However, when I attempt to do this I get the following error messages:

```
creationDate = null;
```

"Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type"

```
exRecNo = null;
```

"Cannot convert null to 'byte' because it is a non-nullable value type"

Since I can't set them to null is there any way that I can clear their values?

Comment: Maybe you could use `DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: You could make them Nullable - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: You don't need to assign these variables to null if you setting the value within the while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To declare a primitive / non-nullable types as nullable use a `?`

```
DateTime? creationDate;
byte? exRecNo;
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  for the full explanation.

Comment: Very interesting I had no idea you could do that.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 5):

No.

The definition of a value type is that there is no separate "null" or "empty" value.
Those variables **always** hold a value, even before you assign any.

You could set them to their *default* values, which are `1/1/0001` and `0`, respectively.

Alternatively, you could use nullable types, which allocate extra storage to be able to hold a `null` value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
DateTime? creationDate;
byte? exRecNo;
```

For nullable types

Comment: Very interesting I didn't know that was possible.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I use them alot esp when I'm dealing with a value from my DB that is a nullable field. There are plenty of times that `null` is a valid value and that's what using these nullable types can be for

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable within the While loop - in other words, use block scope...

Answer (score 2):

Use [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) `DateTime?` or `byte?`

You can't clear their values, you can set them to default values:

```
  creationDate = new DateTime(); // this gets you {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
  exRecNo = 0; // or new Byte();
```